# Remove groups with size smaller than mean group size in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'case': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar'],
                             'cluster': [1, 1, 1, 2, 1],
                             'conf': [1, 2, 3, 1, 1]})

df
Out[3]: 
  case  cluster  conf
0  foo        1     1
1  foo        1     2
2  foo        1     3
3  foo        2     1
4  bar        1     1
```

If I group by 'case' and 'cluster', I can remove the elements belonging to groups with only 1 element:

```
df.groupby(['case', 'cluster']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
Out[4]: 
  case  cluster  conf
0  foo        1     1
1  foo        1     2
2  foo        1     3
```

I can also compute the mean number of elements per group for each 'case' value:

```
df.groupby(['case', 'cluster']).size().mean(level='case')
Out[5]: 
case
bar    1
foo    2
dtype: int64
```

But, how can I filter out the elements belonging to groups with less elements than the corresponding mean value? The output I am expecting is:

```
  case  cluster  conf
0  foo        1     1
1  foo        1     2
2  foo        1     3
4  bar        1     1
```

Comment: You could use `pd.merge` to merge some of your results and then apply boolean masking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `name` parameter of a group to perform a lookup on the mean group size Series while using `filter`:

```
grp_mean = df.groupby(['case', 'cluster']).size().mean(level='case')
df = df.groupby(['case', 'cluster']).filter(lambda x: len(x) >= grp_mean[x.name[0]])
```

As pointed out by @MaxU, this could be slightly sped up by factoring out the `groupby`:

```
g = df.groupby(['case', 'cluster'])
grp_mean = g.size().mean(level='case')
df = g.filter(lambda x: len(x) >= grp_mean[x.name[0]])
```

The resulting output:

```
  case  cluster  conf
0  foo        1     1
1  foo        1     2
2  foo        1     3
4  bar        1     1
```

Comment: @MaxU:  I did some tests, and factoring out the `groupby` does give a slight performance boost if you add an intermediate calculation of the mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 2;b =1
pd.concat( [df[(df.conf >= a) & (df.case == 'foo')], df[(df.conf >= b) & (df.case == 'bar')] ])

  case  cluster  conf
1  foo  1        2   
2  foo  1        3   
4  bar  1        1
```